# get gstreamer audioconvert to output signed 32-bit floats from -1 to 1

Tags: gstreamer, web-audio-api

Trying to figure out how to get gstreamer to output raw audio data as signed 32-bit floats in the range of -1 to 1.

Here's what I've got so far, but these values are unsigned and not in the scale of -1 to 1:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="sound.mp3" ! mad ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! capsfilter caps="audio/x-raw, format=F32BE, rate=44100, channels=1" ! filesink location=sound.raw`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I can confirm that GStreamer by far exceeds the range `[-1,1]`. Also it seems to me that there's no really simple solution to that problem if you want to use GStreamer (you could write a postprocessor that takes a raw 32bit-signed integer file and convert each 4-byte chunk to float, but that's a bit hacky).

I can however offer you an alternative solution using [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org):

```
avconv -i /path/to/input/file.mp3 -f f32be -ac 1 /path/to/output_float.raw
```

I successfully played the output file using `aplay`:

```
aplay -r 44100 -f FLOAT_BE -c1 /path/to/output_float.raw
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can change/add to the caps:

```
- audio/x-raw  to audio/x-raw-float

- signed=true
```